# Asterisk BridgeWait How to bridge into a general bridge

Tags: asterisk

I need to connect two channels from a bunch of channels. The upcoming channel is pushed into BridgeWait. Waiting music is played. Under the data is placed about the current case. I want to find out why we need BridgeWait. I try to create new ordinal bridge with the channel by [AMI Bridge](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+ManagerAction_Bridge) I do not see an error. New bridge is not created. Channels are still in the bridge "Waiting". If I kick from the waiting bridge the channel is closed so it is impossible to bridge them again.

***How should I bridge channels from the waiting bridge correctly.***

*extensions.conf*

```
exten => 2002,1,NoOp
exten => 2002,n,BridgeWait("Waiting")
exten => 2002,n,Hangup
```

***Channels***

```
924fa28457df*CLI> core show channels
Channel              Location             State   Application(Data)             
SIP/100-0000000a     2002@default:2       Up      BridgeWait("Waiting")         
SIP/103-00000009     2002@default:2       Up      BridgeWait("Waiting")         
2 active channels
2 active calls
11 calls processed
```

***Holding bridge*** There are two channels.

```
924fa28457df*CLI> bridge show f57050e0-b6ae-4bfc-b8e3-295ce7371fef
Id: f57050e0-b6ae-4bfc-b8e3-295ce7371fef
Type: base
Technology: holding_bridge
Num-Channels: 2
Channel: SIP/103-00000009
Channel: SIP/100-0000000a
```

Comment: You have unbridge first before bridge again. Where is your code?

Comment: You are right. It is not possible to implement now. I've resolved it by AGI approach. But these are very different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to implement without AGI.

```
; Queue processing pipe.
exten => 2002,1,NoOp
exten => 2002,n,BridgeWait("Waiting")
exten => 2002,n,AGI(agi://10.1.2.1:3007)
exten => 2002,n,Hangup
```

[image]
BridgeWait Asterisk application holds the call for further processing with less resources.
Dialplan consists of piped operations: bridge wait and the next AGI management.
BridgeWait is broken from outside through the AMI interface to be managed by AGI when an operator is defined.
Short AGI pipe connects this predefined client and operator by dial command.